# Handle input with parentheses

Tags: python

I need help to manipulate the input of my code, the input passes a sequence of parentheses with values to insert into a binary seach tree, the code to mount the tree is ready the problem is only to handle the input.

The input is like this:

(12(7(3()())(10()(11()())))(23(17()())(31()())))

Basically, Root (left)(right), in this case don't know how can i get this values to add at the tree, for example, 12 to root, 7 to right, etc...
My code:

```
class No():
    def __init__(self, dado):
        self.dado = dado
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class ArvoreBinariaBusca():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = None

    def Inserir(self, dado, raiz_atual):
        if self.raiz is None:
            self.raiz = No(dado)
            return

        if dado < raiz_atual.dado:
            if raiz_atual.left is None:
                raiz_atual.left = No(dado)
                return
            else:
                self.Inserir(dado, raiz_atual.left)

        else:
            if raiz_atual.right is None:
                raiz_atual.right = No(dado)
                return
            else:
                self.Inserir(dado, raiz_atual.right)
        return
```

I try to do something like this:

```
def OrganizarArvore(self, string, raiz_atual):
    if self.raiz is None:
        if string[1] != ')':
            self.raiz = No(int(string[1]))
        self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], self.raiz)
    else:
        if raiz_atual.left is None:
            raiz_atual.left = No(int(string[1]))
            self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], raiz_atual.left)
        else:
            self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], raiz_atual.left)
```

But didn't work.

Comment: Writing a recursive parser for this format is very easy. If you have a case like `()`, you return `None`. Else you call the same parser function to parse the left subtree and the right subtree, and make a node with the value and two subtrees. You only have to look up 1 character or token after a `(` to detect if it's a `()` or a node with a value.

Comment: I thought so, but before do I need to break the correct string? I tried with the split, but I could not.

Comment: Why dont you try with `find()`

Comment: Look at [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html). Try e.g. `import tokenize, StringIO; tokenize.tokenize(StringIO.StringIO('(3()(2()()))').readline)`

Comment: @9000 i try, but i have some problems, for example, if i have the case like this (11(, they only save 1 and not 11, my code...

Comment: def OrganizarArvore(self, string, raiz_atual):
        if self.raiz is None:
            if string[1] != ')':
                self.raiz = No(int(string[1]))
            self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], self.raiz)
        else:
            if raiz_atual.left is None:
                raiz_atual.left = No(int(string[1]))
                self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], raiz_atual.left)
            else:
                self.OrganizarArvore(string[2:-1], raiz_atual.left)